# Destroying InfiniteScroll on AJAX page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

We have a website that is running [jQuery Infinite Scroll Plugin](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll). The plugin is no longer maintained but it is the only one that really serves our purpose properly. However, the problem I have is that our site is ajax based. On page change the `pg-changed` trigger is fired against the window, which allows us to check if the Infinite Scroll container is there and enable Infinite Scroll. If the Infinite Scroll container isn't there but `$.infscr` exists, we will attempt to destroy the previous instance.

The problem I am having is that when changing to another page, it doesn't seem to be getting destroyed properly and sometimes AJAX calls will be made, along with the infscr loading bar displaying. Here is the code I am using to instantiate and destroy the plugin:

```
$(window).on('pg-changed', function () {

  // delete our infinite scroll
  if(typeof $.infscr !== 'undefined') {

    $('.snap-inner, .infscr').data('infinitescroll', null);
    $('.snap-inner, .infscr').infinitescroll('unbind');
    $('.snap-inner, .infscr').infinitescroll('destroy');
    $('#infscr-loading').remove();

    $.infscr.data('infinitescroll', null);
    $.infscr.infinitescroll('unbind');
    $.infscr.infinitescroll('destroy');

    delete $.infscr;
  }

  // setup our infinite scroll
  if($('.infscr').length) {

    $.infscr = $('.infscr').infinitescroll({

      // define our navigation selectors
      navSelector   : 'div.infscr-navigation',
      nextSelector  : 'div.infscr-navigation A:first',
      itemSelector  : '.infscr-item',

      // allow scrolling an overflowed element
      behavior      : 'local',
      bufferPx      : 120,
      binder        : $('.snap-inner'),

      dataType      : 'html',

      loading   : {
        msg         : null,
        selector    : '.snap-content',
        img         : 'data:image/gif;base64,TRIMMED',
        msgText     : '<span class="infscr-loading">Loading...</span>',
      }
    }, function (arrayOfNewElems) {

      // render background images on our new elements
      $(this).renderBgImages();

    });
  }

});
```

I really hope you can help with this as it has become quite a problem now, firing on scroll, making AJAX calls and displaying the loading bar.

Comment: Does it ever enter the if(typeof $.infscr !== 'undefined') condition?

Comment: @phenxd thanks for your message - yes it does meet the condition I have tested by outputting to console and it does try and destroy when changing page it just isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem might be that the plugin binds events on elements external to itself. It's hard to say without further debugging (is the plugin deleted or does it fail to do so?). If it does, why would it fail to unbind the events? etc.

When you say, 'on another page', I suppose you are not loading a whole new page (which would 'reset' the javascript.

Though, depending on wether this could work for you, you might want to try unbinding ALL events on the document, and starting fresh.

```
$(document).add('*').off();
```

should do so. If it does, you could try to pinpoint what elements/events you need to unbind manually. Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: I will give this a go tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Appreciate your help! I suppose to debug I can bind to all events and log them to the console and see when this condition is actually being met